# How to have custom table headers in ALL list view for Salesforce and Publish it in Package

Tags: list-view, package

How do we apply a custom layout to the "All" list view? I want to show multiple headers like name, date, etc.
I have a custom object and want to publish it in a package on App Exchange. The All list view only has the ID by default and I wish for it to have multiple fields.
I could set headers by clicking on the filter icon but still haven't found a way to persist it and publish it in the package.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.